# Unhandled exception when calling a SetWindowLongPtr

Tags: c++, winapi

```
void IronmanMap::CommandLine()
{
     mode = 1;
    InvalidateRect(storedhwnd, NULL, 1);

    HWND hmmitem;
    hmmitem = GetDlgItem(storedhwnd, ID_EDITBOX1);

    backupproc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hmmitem, GWLP_WNDPROC,     (LONG)EditProc);

    SetFocus(hmmitem);

}
```

When this function gets to the closing brace it says there is an unhandled exception.

Comment: Why did you truncate your 64-bit `EditProc` to a 32-bit integer? That seems wrong.

Comment: [mcve] please. Certainly looking at your window proc would be instructive.

Comment: You should be using `SetWindowSubclass()`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter So he should, I always forget about that one.

Answer (score 2):

That line of code should be:

```
backupproc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hmmitem, GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)EditProc);
```

But Raymond is so *fast*! :)

**Edit:** Jonathon Potter comments above that there's a better way to do this (and it's Microsoft's recommended way).  So please ignore the above and subclass your window like this:

```
SetWindowSubclass (hmmitem, EditProc, EditProcSubclassID, EditProcReferenceData);
```

Where:

- `EditProcSubclassID` is a unique ID of your choice (just make one up).
- `EditProcReferenceData` will be passed to `EditProc` whenever it is called.  You can use this for anything you like (or just pass 0).

You then implement `EditProc` like this (note the two extra parameters on the end there):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK EditProc (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    ...
}
```

So what happened to `backupproc`?  Well, you don't need that anymore.  Instead, to call the next WndProc in the chain, call `DefSubclassProc()` (or not, if you want to swallow the message) at the end of `EditProc`.

Finally, if you want to detach `EditProc` from the window, call `RemoveWindowSubclass()`.

The main advantage of this approach is that it works correctly if somebody else subclasses the window after you do (or, indeed, before, if they want to remove their WndProc before you do).  That's why you should use it.

Read the [`SetWindowSubclass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) documentation on MSDN, and see Raymond's blog on [Safer subclassing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883).

Comment: Won't explain the issue if it's a 32 bit process.

Comment: The only reason to call `SetWindowLongPtr()` vs `SetWindowLong()` is to support 64bit compiling. Now granted, in a 32bit compile, `SetWindowLongPtr()` maps to `SetWindowLong()`, though...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What do you think the odds are?

Comment: I'd say that the odds were high that the asker is compiling for 32 bit. Furthermore, what are the odds on the truncation even mattering? Is it likely the code address is >4GB?  If I were to bet, I'd bet that the defect is in the window proc itself. Either wrong signature, or bad logic inside proc. But since the question is missing information all we can do is guess. And your answer is just a guess. Personally I'd close vote the question as off topic (no MCVE) and not write an answer that is a guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, I'll set out my master plan: post a short answer, might work, might not.  If not, ask OP to post code of `EditProc`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The [default base address for a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/base-base-address) in a 64-bit application is `0x180000000`. That's well beyond the 4GB boundary, and truncation in a 64-bit application is highly likely to matter. But then, we don't know, and can only guess.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I believe that `SetWindowLongPtr()` is now the recommended way on all platforms.  But as JonathonPotter points out, one should use `SetWindowSubclass()` anyway.  I have added that to my answer.